# Libgdx table structure

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a problem with Table attributes on Libgdx my code:

```
 Table root = new Table();
    root.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(root);


    Table table = new Table(MyGdxGame.gameSkin);
    table.setBackground(new NinePatchDrawable(getNinePatch(("background.jpg"))));
    root.add(table).grow().pad(25.0f);

    Label label = new Label("Marsel\nTale", MyGdxGame.gameSkin, "title");
    label.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    label.setScale(.9f,.9f);
    table.add(label);
    table.row();

    TextButton playButton = new TextButton("Tournament",MyGdxGame.gameSkin);
    playButton.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new ChampionScreen(game));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    table.add(playButton);

    TextButton optionsButton = new TextButton("Options",MyGdxGame.gameSkin);
    optionsButton.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(new OptionScreen(game));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    table.add(optionsButton).padBottom(3.0f);
```

I'm not able to modify the structure of my table, I want to put playButton and optionButton in the bottom.

Comment: show your desire in pictorial representation

Answer (score 1):

There should be a method called `bottom()` that you can use on the buttons like:

```
table.add(playButton).bottom();
```

More information can be found in this helpful article: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table